# remove nomenclature header in elsarticle appendix

Tags: header-footer, elsarticle, appendix, nomencl

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[authoryear, review]{elsarticle} %preprint

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{nomencl} 

\xpatchcmd{\thenomenclature}{%
  \section*{\nomname}% Look for `\section*... etc.
}{% Replace it by 'nothing'
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}

\makenomenclature 

\begin{document}
\section{Section example}
This is my text, where variables appear.
\nomenclature[1]{$\mu$}{Example variable}

\appendix
\section{Definition of model variables}
\printnomenclature[0.9in]
\end{document}
```

As you see I have the nomenclature within an appendix, and I use `xpatch` to remove the nomenclature header added by the nomenclature package. This used to work, but I updated my `elsarticle` class, and I think this is the reason it stopped working. I would be grateful if I could get some help addressing this issue.

Also, related to the appendix, I would like to remove the word `Appendix` including the space after it from the appendix heading. I added:

```
\let\appendixname\relax
```

... to the preamble, but while this removes the word `Appendix`, it also leaves the pre-existing space between `Appendix` and `A`. Any solutions to this additional question would be very welcome as well.

Comment: You should contact the elsevier support if you are publishing in one of their journals: elsarticle@stmdocs.in

Comment: **@DG'**: meanwhile, I solved the first problem myself, by using a more direct approach and changing the definitions of `\thenomenclature` instead. As for the second problem, I will most likely solve it either by exploiting `appendix` package definitions, commands, etc. or by redefining the `subappendices` environment of the latter package, so that it appropriately generates alphabetic and numeric section and subsection counters, respectively, within the document appendix or appendices. Thanks anyway..............

Comment: Don't get me wrong: If you are publishing with elsevier, you'd better check with them, before changing the template, they might not accept your modifications. If you are not, why bother with `elsarticle`?